# How to explicitly refer to the current uncommited state of a repo in a git diff

Tags: git

When you run `git diff` or `git diff <some commit>` you're implicitly diffing the current state of the repo (whether staged or unstaged) implicitly against `HEAD` implicitly in the first case or whatever commit is specified in the latter case.

My question is: how do I explicitly refer to the current state of the repo?
Ideally, I'd like to be calling something like `git diff CURRENT_STATE HEAD`.

Comment: `git diff HEAD` is (contrarily to the behaviour of most git commands) different than `git diff`. I'm unsure about what you precisely want, but could it suit your needs?

Comment: what does *current state of the repo* mean, the remote repo? You are referring to the current state of your repo

Comment: By current state of the repo, I meant more current state of the local files. Basically, I'm asking: Does the uncommitted state of the repo explicitly have its own ref?

Answer (score 3):

> how do I explicitly refer to the current state of the [work tree]?

`git diff` is already an explicit reference to that, Git compares against the current state of the work tree unless you override it and tell it to compare against content somewhere else instead, but if you're after a further override like `--no-cached` to override any earlier `--cached` override, that, `git diff` doesn't have at the moment, you'll have to write a little options preprocessor to strip out anything you don't like rather than just tacking the override on the end.

edit:

> Ideally, I'd like to be calling something like `git diff CURRENT_STATE HEAD`

You can get this effect with `-R`, a reverse diff that swaps the usual order. You'd do that specific diff with just `git diff -R HEAD` (I much prefer the `@` synonym for `HEAD`, `git diff -R @`).

Answer (score 3):

[jthill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58289724/1256452) is fine; I just want to address this comment directly, with much more detail and formatting than will fit into a comment:

> Basically, I'm asking: Does the uncommitted state of the repo explicitly have its own ref?

The short answer is "no".

A ref, like `HEAD` or `master` or (fully spelled out) `refs/heads/master`, ultimately resolves to a hash ID.<sup>1</sup>  If it's a branch name or remote-tracking name, it resolves specifically to a *commit* hash ID; if it's a *tag* name, it may resolve to any of Git's four internal object types: commit, tree, blob, or (annotated) tag.

A tree object is the closest thing you can get to the work-tree, but it's not the work-tree at all.  In fact, there are *two* uncommitted representations, in a normal Git repository, that you cannot refer to by name.  One of these is the stuff that is in the *index*—essentially, the proposed next commit—and the other is the stuff in the work-tree.

If the index is in a good state,<sup>2</sup> you can run `git write-tree`.  The result is a hash ID.  This is not a reference name at all, it's just a hash ID, but a hash ID is usually just as good.  So if you'd like some Git command to take notice of the proposed next commit, you can run `git write-tree` to write it to a tree object, and then use the resulting hash ID.

The work-tree, however, isn't at all suitable for this.  To turn the work-tree into a hash ID, you need to write it to the—or at least *an*—index and then run `git write-tree`.  You can use the environment variable `GIT_INDEX_FILE` to name a temporary file that will hold a temporary index.

The `git diff` and `git status` commands have built-in tricks to use the index and work-tree *as if* they were commits, but most other Git commands don't.

---

<sup>1</sup>If the ref is *symbolic*—as `HEAD` usually is—it just contains the name of another ref.  If that other ref doesn't actually exist, the symbolic ref won't resolve to a hash ID at all, and `git rev-parse` will fail on it, but `git symbolic-ref` will let you examine the target.

<sup>2</sup>The index can be in the *merge conflict* state, in which it *can't* be converted into a tree object. In this case `git write-tree` just errors out.  Unfortunately, there is no good way to deal with this other than just to resolve the merge conflicts.  I say "unfortunately" because it would sometimes be very handy to stash (as if by `git stash` or some such) the conflicted state for safekeeping and/or transport, and the way Git is today, that's simply not possible.  You can get pretty close, using `git ls-files --stage` to translate the index into text and `git update-index` to invert that, but protecting temporary blob hashes from GC is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify two commits to git diff:

```
git diff [--options] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>...]
   This is to view the changes between two arbitrary <commit>.
```

Please write:

```
git help diff
```

For more options.

Good luck!